# Bash script: Check if shared file is open on another server

Tags: linux, bash, file-access

So I have 3 servers, s1, s2 and d1 where d1 is a samba server.  The process I have is that an script running on s1 generates files and copies them to d1, s2 then picks up those files from d1 and runs some processes on them.

My issue is that on s2 I need to make sure that s1 have completely finished writing the file to d1 before I pick it up.  These are sometimes large files so its possible that based on the crontab setup I have on s2 there could be overlapping where s1 is still trying to copy the file when s2 is ready to pick it up.

My first inclination was to use lsof but that only tells me what files are being used by the server running the command, not if another server is using the file.  any ideas on how I can script this file checking?

Comment: What about `flock`?  Locking works over NFS, but honestly I have no idea for samba.

Comment: @FatalError so your saying that when s1 is copying the file use flock to lock the file so that s2 cannot access it?  I don't think i can use any samba related commands at all anyways since those would have to be run from d1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you've got your local machine and user's public key in the remote machine and user's authorized_keys file, you could run the lsof via ssh and grep for the filename

```
ssh user@host lsof | grep filename
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        docommand
    else
        dontdoit
fi
```

Comment: That is def a possible solution, but its one of those things where I never trusted that type of access in general for a security standpoint.  anytime i can ssh into something w/out having to provide credentials I always feel like the system is insecure.  but Its something i can look into more for sure

Comment: it only works if you've got access to a specific account on a specific machine with a specific public key, and that key is registered with the target machine. So essentially, your security is all about protecting that account. From that perspective, it's about as secure as sudo, but doesn't give a root account. 

To lock it down further you can edit your hosts-allow file to only let that machine (and user, if you like) connect.